# Faulty "normed" option in python matplotlib.pyplot.hist?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was working on data using pyspark using iPython, when I came across the normed option and when I turned normed option off, it still showed me relative frequencies. Whereas, by skipping the normed option, it will show frequencies and not relative frequencies. Is it a bug in source code of Matplotlib?

```
In [17]: hist(ages, bins = 20, color = 'lightblue', normed = 'False')
Out[17]: 
(array([ 0.00064269,  0.00192808,  0.00449886,  0.0279572 , 0.02956393,
     0.03374144,  0.04563129,  0.02538642,  0.02088756,  0.01863813,
     0.02088756,  0.01606735,  0.0170314 ,  0.01863813,  0.00674829,
     0.00482021,  0.0054629 ,  0.00192808,  0.00128539,  0.00128539]),
array([  7. ,  10.3,  13.6,  16.9,  20.2,  23.5,  26.8,  30.1,  33.4,
     36.7,  40. ,  43.3,  46.6,  49.9,  53.2,  56.5,  59.8,  63.1,
     66.4,  69.7,  73. ]),
<a list of 20 Patch objects>)

In [18]: hist(ages, bins = 20, color = 'lightblue', normed = 'True')
Out[18]: 
(array([ 0.00064269,  0.00192808,  0.00449886,  0.0279572 ,  0.02956393,
     0.03374144,  0.04563129,  0.02538642,  0.02088756,  0.01863813,
     0.02088756,  0.01606735,  0.0170314 ,  0.01863813,  0.00674829,
     0.00482021,  0.0054629 ,  0.00192808,  0.00128539,  0.00128539]),
array([  7. ,  10.3,  13.6,  16.9,  20.2,  23.5,  26.8,  30.1,  33.4,
     36.7,  40. ,  43.3,  46.6,  49.9,  53.2,  56.5,  59.8,  63.1,
     66.4,  69.7,  73. ]),
<a list of 20 Patch objects>)
```

Comment: `normed` should be a boolean not a string in `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` (see http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist)

Comment: @EdSmith You should post that as an answer!

Comment: @Brian L done, in case it helps someone else. I originally edited to include the pyspark tag thinking it may be something more involved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument `normed` expects a boolean not a string in `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`. From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist),

> **normed** : boolean, optional
>
> If **True**, the first element of the return tuple will be the counts normalized to form a probability density, i.e., `n/(len(x)dbin)`, i.e., the integral of the histogram will sum to 1. If *stacked* is also *True*, the sum of the histograms is normalized to 1.
>
> Default is `False`

Comment: Thanks @Ed Smith! It left me wondering, how was the above code accepted. Did python just ignore the string and assumed it to be bool `True`?

Comment: python accepts any non-empty string as `True`, e.g. `bool("True")=True` and `bool("False")=True` while `bool("") = False`. Probably correct in the interest of duck typing but maybe pyplot should flag error in keyword booleans supplied as strings...